# Unpredictable routing error for 'show' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Recent item - Routing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982083/recent-item-routing-error)

I'm encountering a really strange behaviour in my rails app. Basicaly, user is able to upload photo (using carrierwave, basic scaffold-generated form). The model for those photos is called `user_photo`. Here is my routing file:

**routing.rb**

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  #...

  match 'profiles/:profile_id/photos' => 'user_photos#index_profile', :as => :profile_user_photos
  match 'user_photos/vote/:id'   => 'user_photos#vote',       :as => :user_photo_vote
  resources :user_photos do
    resources :comments
  end

  #...
end
```

And now, when i'm trying to access some of photos uploaded by users using the following URL pattern:

```
http://localhost:3000/user_photos/31 (this is just an example)
```

i'm getting this error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user_photos",
> :id=>nil}

The strange thing is that some of user_photos works, it's totally unpredictable! I'm not sure what is probably causing this error so i have posted just my routing file (cause it's the first thing that comes to my mind). If you have any ideas or need anything more to understand what's going on, please just let me know. Thanks in advance.

---

#### Edit:

Ok, actually it's predictable. Only the last uploaded user_photo is not working, when i'll upload the next one, previous one which was not working starts to work. Any ideas?

This thread is continued here: [Recent item - Routing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982083/recent-item-routing-error)

Comment: can you pate the code of the link or the image that you are trying to use to access the photos?

Comment: Sorry, i have forgot about this obvious thing. I have edited the original post, please take a look

Comment: try using user_photo_url(@photo) where @photo is the photo that you are trying to access

Comment: i'm using `user_photo_path(@user_phto)` on `index` action while listing all user_photos and it works

Answer (score 2):

Try out:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  #...

  match 'profiles/:profile_id/photos' => 'user_photos#index_profile', :as => :profile_user_photos
  resources :user_photos do
    get :vote, :on => :member
    resources :comments
  end

  #...
end
```

The line `get :vote, :on => :member` will produce the route `/user_photos/:id/vote` which you can call with `like_user_photo_path(any_user_photo)`

Comment: yeah, looks much better now, thanks for a tip :) but the routing for `show` action is still broken and my question stays unresolved

Comment: can you show your user_photos controller, please

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://gist.github.com/cb713a2b7e6c984797ce . I've just noticed strange thing - after about 40 minutes from the moment i've created this UserPhoto, it's now working. Maybe it's some kind of cache ? I'm running my app in dev env using passenger + apache2

Comment: Ok, i have some new facts, please check the `Edit` section in original post.