# Recent item - Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm encountering a really strange behaviour in my rails app. Basicaly, user is able to upload photo. The model for those photos is called user_photo. The thing is that allways, when i'll try to access the most recently added item (using the URL generated by `user_photo_path(@user_photo)`, let's say it's `http://localhost:3000/user_photos/20`), i'm getting this error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user_photos", :id=>nil}

This happens **just to most recently added item** which means that if i have a recently added `user_photo` with `:id => 20` it will cause the routing error; however, if i'll create the new one (with `:id => 21`), the previous user_photo which id is 20 will start to work.

Have you any idea what can be causing this strange behaviour? I'm running my rails app in dev env using apache2 + passenger

Comment: Can we see your controller code for `user_photos`?

Comment: can you show me routes file specified path

Comment: code from your routes file should help us more . also do a rake routes on your app and see the path that the command renders

Comment: Sure, controller: https://gist.github.com/cb713a2b7e6c984797ce and routes: https://gist.github.com/33a3e9fbe296862ac408

Comment: what do you see when you do rake routes?

Comment: `rake routes`: https://gist.github.com/0fcadfd623940c2c52b4

Comment: your routes and controller look good but your model is not reloading the data as you save it. Use @user_photo.reload  in your create action after you save the data and see if it works .(add this after line no 66 per your controller gist )

Comment: I don't think it's a route problem... which db are you using? Are you specifying the ids? have you called `@user_photo.save`?  What does `@user_photo.persisted?` return?

Comment: Like the previous commenter, I think you are messing up the concept of when an object is actually saved. For example, on line 70 of your controller you are trying to render a page for a model that you failed to persist. Something similar is probably what is messed up when you are calling the path helper.